# MVC application with case and switch

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, runtime, switch-statement, html.textboxfor

I am building an **MVC 4** application and i am trying to *disable*  one **TextBoxFor** (or add some text) if another **TextBoxFor** has been entered. Was trying to use switch-case statement but so far no luck. Because i have to add text/disable other **TextBoxFor** this has to be run in *runtime*.

Part of the Create View code:

```
<div class="editor-label2"> 
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First)
 </div>
 div class="editor-field2">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.First, new {  @id = "id1"} )
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First)
 </div>

  <div class="editor-label3">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Second)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field3">
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Second, new {  @id = "id2"} )
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Second)
   </div>
```

---

and this:

```
@{ 
   switch (id1)
   {
     case 1:    
         <text> text1 </text>
         break;
     case 2:    
         <text> text2 </text>
         break;
     default:
         <text> text </text>
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at using something like KnockOut for this? it is great  for things just like the ones you are describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some jquery to detect if a textbox has a value and otherwise disable it.

```
$('input:text').filter(function () { return $.trim($(this).val()) == ''; })
               .attr("disabled", true);
```

If you are wanting to do it after the user enters a value (i.e. at runtime) then put the statement inside the "on change" event of the textboxes.

```
$('input:text]').on('change', function ()
{
    $('input:text').filter(function () { return $.trim($(this).val()) == ''; })
                   .attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: this will work for me if but how can i disable specific textbox with id when another textbox has some value? if i replace first $('input:text') with some id i can disable that one but how do i disable another?